# java.io.NotSerializableException: DStream checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their functions are not serializable

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, stream

When executing this code in Spark Streaming, I got a Serialization error (see below):

```
  val endPoint = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf").getConfig("conf").getString("endPoint")
  val operation = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf").getConfig("conf").getString("operation")
  val param = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf").getConfig("conf").getString("param")

    result.foreachRDD{jsrdd =>
      jsrdd.map(jsobj => {
        val docId = (jsobj \ "id").as[JsString].value
        val response: HttpResponse[String] = Http(apiURL + "/" + endPoint + "/" + docId + "/" + operation).timeout(connTimeoutMs = 1000, readTimeoutMs = 5000).param(param,jsobj.toString()).asString
        val output = Json.parse(response.body) \ "annotation" \ "tags"
        jsobj.as[JsObject] + ("tags", output.as[JsObject])
    })}
```

So, as I understand, the problem is with scalaj Http api. How can I resolve this issue? Obviously I cannot change the api.

> java.io.NotSerializableException: DStream checkpointing has been
>   enabled but the DStreams with their functions are not serializable
>   org.consumer.kafka.KafkaJsonConsumer
>   Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.consumer.kafka.KafkaJsonConsumer,
>   value:
>   org.consumer.kafka.KafkaJsonConsumer@f91da5e)
>     - field (class: org.consumer.kafka.KafkaJsonConsumer$$anonfun$run$1,
>   name: $outer, type: class
>   org.consumer.kafka.KafkaJsonConsumer)
>     - object (class org.consumer.kafka.KafkaJsonConsumer$$anonfun$run$1,
>   )
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3,
>   name: cleanedF$1, type: interface scala.Function1)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3,
>   )
>     - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream, org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@761956ac)
>     - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData, [ 0
>   checkpoint files
>
> ])
>     - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream, org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@704641e3)
>     - element of array (index: 0)
>     - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 16)
>     - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
>     - object (class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, ArrayBuffer(org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@704641e3,
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@761956ac))
>     - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData, [ 0
>   checkpoint files
>
> ])

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: is there any solution for this ?